# Triggering widget animation from outside widget

Tags: flutter, widget, state

I have a custom widget that has normal / animated state. Sometimes I want to be it animated, and sometimes static.

I have made a simple test project to demonstrate my problem: test page contains my custom widget (`ScoreBoard`) and 2 buttons to start / stop animating scoreboard. My problem, that ScoreBoard is not animated, even if I start animation.

Here is my code:

`TestPage`:

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  bool _animate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animate = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          ScoreBoard(
            text: "Hello, world!",
            animate: _animate,
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("START animation"),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _animate = true;
              });
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("STOP animation"),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _animate = false;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ScoreBoard widget:

```
class ScoreBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final bool animate;

  const ScoreBoard({Key key, this.text, this.animate}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScoreBoardState createState() => _ScoreBoardState();
}

class _ScoreBoardState extends State<ScoreBoard>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      vsync: this,
    )..forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.animate
        ? ScaleTransition(
            child:
                Text(widget.text, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1),
            scale: new CurvedAnimation(
              parent: _controller,
              curve: Curves.easeIn,
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            child:
                Text(widget.text, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1),
          );
  }
}
```

Would you be so kind to help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: your controller is `forward()`ed only when you init your state

Comment: where should I forward it?

Comment: you should do that to trigger your `ScaleTransition`

Comment: Thx, a lot, I mean in which method and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

If you initialize an `AnimationController` widget and do not specify arguments for `lowerBound` and `upperBound` (which is the case here), your animation is going to start by default with `lowerBound` 0.0.

> AnimationController({double value, Duration duration, String debugLabel, double lowerBound: 0.0, double upperBound: 1.0, AnimationBehavior animationBehavior: AnimationBehavior.normal, @required TickerProvider vsync })
>   Creates an animation controller. [...]

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html

If you initialize the state of your widget `ScoreBoard`, the method `forward` gets called only once during the whole lifetime of your app. The method `forward` makes that your animation increases from the `lowerBound` (0.0) to the `upperBound` (1.0) within 1 second.

> Starts running this animation forwards (towards the end).

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController/forward.html

In our case, there is no way back once the method `forward` got called. We are only able to stop the animation.

Press Ctrl + F5 for a full restart of the app to see the animation.
To make it even clearer, change the duration of your animation to 10 seconds.

Btw. since Dart 2 you do not need to use the `new` keyword.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      vsync: this,
    )..forward();
  }
```

**Example**

To see what happens you could add this to your `build` method:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Execute 'reverse' if the animation is completed
    if (_controller.isCompleted)
      _controller.reverse();
    else if (_controller.isDismissed)
      _controller.forward();
    // ...
```

... and do not call the method `forward` in the `initState` method:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do not call the method forward in the initState method - Worked for me. Thanks!